# Does Gnome-Shell require more resources from my memory and/or hardware than Unity?

Tags: unity, 11.10, gnome

I found a script online which lets me confirm that Unity will work just fine with my computer (I think I found it on OMGU! if anyone needs the link I'll add it) but when I try to log in using Gnome-Shell the system hangs badly, even when doing things as simple as trying to browse my applications.  Is it possible that I would have problems running Gnome-Shell even though Unity 3D works fine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. Gnome Shell uses Mutter whereas the standard Unity uses Compiz. Since they're different solutions, they have different requirements with regards to drivers. That means Unity might work well and Gnome Shell not, or vice versa.

Comment: Thanks!  And it's just as well I suppose... I prefer Unity, I just wanted to play around with GNOME-Shell a bit.  I installed 11.10 the day it was finally released, and it came pre-installed with both Unity and GNOME-Shell.  Is it possible I need to download some dependencies in order to get the Shell working properly?

Comment: No, installing the package called gnome-shell should provide anything you need. There are updates for Unity just around the corner, by the way, and they should fix at least some of the known issues with it.